# Node.js/Express - How to restrict file access to user who uploaded it?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, access-control

I am building a web application and users can upload pdf's. Upload is all working fine, where I struggle is how to handle file access.

Currently the files are stored in a separate folder for each user. But anyone who knows the URL can access the files.

my express app uses a JWT bearer token for authentication. Is there a way to also only serve the files in a similar way?

thanks,
MJ

Comment: Conceptually, you need middleware (before whatever route that serves the uploaded files) that checks the username in the URL against the token you have and if they don't match, returns a 403 or 404 depending upon whether you want to disclose that it's a valid URL or not.

Comment: First step: Secure the route with auth middleware to only allow logged-in users to make an API call. Second step: Compare the user ID with that of folder ID(assuming you have it in some form) and allow access based on that. Remember to return relevant status code and message in response.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just realise that I should start with not storing the files in the public folder. Middleware makes sense, appreciate it!